# Multiple require statements using Fat-Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have to include/require multiple libraries in a php file and i am using fat-free framework. 
Following are the statements i am writing

```
require ('lib/auth.php');
require ('DBSettings.php');
$f3 = require ('lib/base.php');
```

but it gives me internal server error 500. only if i comment out first two line the code starts working. i have also tried to do this

```
$f3 = require ('lib/auth.php');
$f3 = require ('DBSettings.php');
$f3 = require ('lib/base.php');
```

but this also does not work. Can someone guide me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$f3 = require ('lib/base.php');` should be the first line. You don't need to require `lib/auth.php` but you should keep `require('DBSettings.php');`. If you still get a 500 error, then the error is coming from `DBSettings.php`.

Answer (score 1):

To Someone running into this error, use autoload function like that

```
    $f3->set('DEBUG', 1);
    $f3->set('AUTOLOAD', 'api/models;api/controller/');
    $params = require 'config/params.php';
```